# index entry that only refers to another entry

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

How can I add an entry to an index (I am using `imakeidx`) that simply refers to another entry, without carrying any page numbers itself? In particular I would use this for abbreviations.

For instance, I would like to have

```
graphics processing unit (GPU), 29, 31, 132
GPU, see graphics processing unit
```

EDIT: adding MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This section talks about Graphics Processing Units \index{graphics processing unit}


\clearpage


\index{GPU|see{graphics processing unit}}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually `\index{GPU|see{graphical processing unit}`, but it depends on the index style and the index processor, so a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) would be useful.

Comment: @cabohah works perfectly in my case. I'm not sure how to make a MWE because I'm using a sizeable bundle that was handed to me by a publisher

Comment: Learning how to create a MWE is crucial. Without it, answering your future questions may be difficult or even impossible.

Comment: If you follow the provided link, you'll find instructions for making an MWE. It is (almost) always possible to make a useful MWE.

Comment: @cabohah @cfr I've created a MWE in Overleaf, however in this setup the proposed `index{GPU|see{graphics processing unit}}` does not work

Comment: The last entry is never written to the `idx`-file. Move it at least before the `\clearpage` or remove the `\clearpage`. BTW: I would recommend to set alias entries always at the first time you add the main entry or even inside the document preamble.

Comment: @cabohah thank you - can you explain why the last entry does not make it into the idx file, and why it's best to have the alias entries in the preamble?

Comment: Index entries are written using `\write` not `\immediate\write`, so they are only written, when the next page output happens. But in your case, there isn't a page output between your `\index{GPU|…}` and `\printindex`. `\printindex` needs to close the `idx` file, because it runs the index processor. So when the page of the index itself is printed, it is too late for the `\index`. With the aliases in the preamble (after `\makeindex`), they are already written with the first shipout. And because the page numbers are not needed, you are sure to not loosing one.